# how to get controls in gstreamer

Tags: qt, gstreamer, pipeline, qwebview

I want to play a video in gstreamer using playbin. I am using QT framework. After playing a video through qwebview(using webview),not able to play the video from http url using gstreamer(using gstreamer).Is it possible to  stop or control the gstreamer pipeline.

```
using webview:
                m_view = new QWebView(this);
                //view->setGeometry(50,140, 600,345);
                m_view->load(QUrl("http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+youtube_id+"?autoplay=1"));


using gstreamer:
                 QString url ="http://203.79.103.221/16Wishes.mp4";


                 url = url.mid(0,url.length()-4);
                 url = url.append(".mp4");
                 QByteArray ba = url.toLocal8Bit();
                 char *c_url = ba.data();

                 load_elements (c_url);
                 qDebug() << c_url;
                mplayer_play();
```

Comment: Information is missing here, what's "m_player_play", what does load_elements_do ?

Comment: m_player_play,load_elements do  the following.                                                       m_player_play : gst_element_set_state(GST_ELEMENT(pipeline_1), GST_STATE_PLAYING)                                                                 load_element:/* Create gstreamer elements */
/* Set the source path to get the stream from */
/* Add Elements to the pipelines */
/*listening for End Of Stream (EOS) events, etc.*/